# How to make button do more than one thing after use

Tags: javascript

First I displayed the div on screen and now I want to use the the button to create that same div(or any other action) after user input.

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "block";
}
```

How do i make the button be able to work again after the first thing it did?

Comment: What makes you think it only works one time?

Comment: You can do multiple things in the function, or you can call `addEventListener` multiple times. It executes all the listeners that you add.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't customary to reuse a UI element in different ways as it tends to confuse the end user. But if you must...

```
 document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", showWelcome);

 function showWelcome() {
   document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("add").removeEventListener("click", showWelcome);
   reassignButton();
 }

function resassignButton(){
   // some decision logic for next button function
   document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", doNextThing);
}

function doNextThing(){
  // removes eventlistener on add button. does whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to remove the handler and then set a new one.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('btn');
ele.addEventListener("click", function click1(){

  //Do stuff for the first click
  this.innerHTML = "Click Me Again";
  alert("Hello");
  
  //Remove the event hendler
  this.removeEventListener("click", click1, true);
  
  //Attach handler for rest of clicks
  ele.addEventListener("click", function click2(){
    alert("You cicked again!");
  }, true);
  
}, true);
```

```html
<button id=btn>Click Me</button>
```

Although it's probably more practical to re-use a single event listener, as assigning and re-assigning event listeners can sometimes lead to memory leaks..

```js
(()=>{
  var ele = document.getElementById('btn');
  var clicks = 0;
  ele.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(clicks){
      alert("Thanks for clicking again");
    }else{
      alert("Hello");
      this.innerHTML = "Click again";
    }
    clicks++;


  }, true);
})();
```

```html
<button id=btn>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make several methods and use these with the `onclick` attribute of button.

Also I advise you to use jQuery. It's easy and faster than JS.

Comment: 1) You can only use a single method with the `onclick` attribute, you must use event listeners if you need more than one. 2) jQuery *IS* JS, and it's actually slower, not faster than plain JS. - That said, if you must mention jQuery at least mention the `$.one` method that solves the problem OP posed.